# Android: Listener on array items

Tags: android, arrays, loops, scope, listener

I have created a For Loop which sets each ImageView an ID and a ClickListener. When the click is pressed, the OnClickListner either doesn't seem to be able to find the ID, or isn't called at all.

```
    public int[] myResources = {R.id.bblock1, R.id.bblock2, R.id.bblock3, R.id.bblock4, R.id.bblock5, R.id.bblock6, R.id.bblock7, R.id.bblock8};
    ImageView[] bblock = new ImageView[7];

for(int i = 0; i==myResources.length; i++) {
                             bblock[i]=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(myResources[i]);
                             bblock[i].setOnClickListener(ActivityCheck);

                      } 



View.OnClickListener ActivityCheck = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void  onClick  (View  v){
                if( v.getId() == (R.id.bblock1)){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/itz_jonno"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);                   
                }
```

^^ The OnClickListener is not able to to find the view. 
Although, WITHOUT using the array and loop the code below does work:

```
ImageView bblock1=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.bblock1);
bbblock1.setOnClickListener(ActivityCheck);
```

Any ideas why the array wont work, but the standard code will?

Comment: use condition for that if ..switch..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `i==myResources.length` into `i < myResources.length`.

The current loop will exit immediately unless `0 == myResources.length`.

(The whole event listener thing was a nice decoy though.)

Comment: Not quite - i<=... will cause an out of bounds exception when i==myResources.length. Try i<myResources.length.

Comment: @barry thank you, fixed :D, I should not do these things in the early morning (but at least the error would be clear).

Comment: I am getting array out of bounds with both <= and <

Comment: That's because you have more resources than (spaces for) blocks. Try `ImageView[] bblock = new ImageView[myResources.length];`

Comment: Sorted! Thanks The Nail and everyone, ImageView[myResources.length] was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Besides problem with a loop,  your Listener will work only for R.id.block1 , it will egnore events for all other views.  What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was hoping the myResources array would solve that by adding each ImageView with the right layout

Comment: I have 8 ImageViews that will be clickable, so rather than write each one out individually, was trying to create a nice loop to tidy up a lot of code

Comment: But your onClick only handles bblock1.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, only written that for testing!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i==myResources.length; i++) {
                             bblock[i]=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(myResources[i]);
                             bblock[i].setOnClickListener(
                                new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void  onClick  (View  v){
                if( write u r checking condition here ){
                   start u r suitable activity here.                 
                }
                             );

                      }
```

Comment: no need to check condition in listener, as there is dedicated listener for each view